# VBA Saltar un error en un With... End With

Tags: vba

Estoy trabajando con vba para el tratamiento de datos dentro de excel, tengo unos informes, cada unos en su hoja, en los que necesito rellenar las celdas que están en blanco con el valor de la celda que tienen por encima de ellas.

El problema es que al acabar la primera hoja, me da un error 1004, y me gustaría que pasara de ese error, y siguiera con la siguiente hoja. El código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
Function structure_sheets()
    With ThisWorkbook
        For Each Sheet In .Sheets
            If (InStrRev(Sheet.Name, "Node") > 0) Then
                LastRow = Sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
                With Range("A8:F" & Range("F" & LastRow).End(xlDown).Row)
                    .SpecialCells(xlBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
                    .Value = .Value
                End With
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Function
```

Y el error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los OnError parece que no funcionan con estos bloques de código.

Si alguien tiene idea, se aceptan sugerencias.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vamos por puntos:

- Las funciones (`Function  structure_sheets()`) se utilizan para devolver un valor, en caso de que no devuelvas nada, que es este caso, debes utilizar el `Sub`.
- Es recomendable, si no obligatorio, declarar todas las variables que utilizas. Para ayudarte con esto, pon `Option Explicit` arriba del todo de tu módulo. Te obligará a declarar todas las variables.
- No hace falta que utilices el `With ThisWorkbook` ya que sólo haces referencia a él una vez.
- Cuando calculas `LastRow` haces referencia correctamente a la hoja (a su vez, referenciada al libro por estar dentro del bucle que lo recorre), pero cuando haces el `Wtih Range...` en ningún momento haces referencia a la hoja, así que si la hoja activa <> la hoja del bucle, eso no te va a salir bien. Debes siempre hacer referencias completas a los rangos: libro-hoja-rango.
- Por último, puedes evitar el error sencillamente contando de antemano si te vas a encontrar con celdas vacías.

Teniendo todo lo anterior en cuenta, así quedaría tu código:

```
Option Explicit
Sub structure_sheets()

    Dim Sheet As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim MiRango As Range
    Dim ContadorVacias As Long
    For Each Sheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If (InStrRev(Sheet.Name, "Node") > 0) Then
            LastRow = Sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
            Set MiRango = Sheet.Range("A8:F" & Sheet.Range("F" & LastRow).End(xlDown).Row)
            ContadorVacias = MiRango.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Cells.Count
            If ContadorVacias = 0 Then GoTo Siguiente
            With MiRango
                .SpecialCells(xlBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
                .Value = .Value
            End With
        End If
Siguiente:
        ContadorVacias = 0
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Oye, pues si, muchas gracias. Estoy volviendo a ponerme con VBA y todavía tengo estas metidas de pata. A seguir bregando con los reportes :D